# jquery matching classes

Tags: jquery

I have a situation where I need to match part of a uniquely generated ID name to that of an div with the same ID, but which is hidden with css.

As such;

```
<a class="popup" id="productTip348_27598" href="#">Link text</a>
```

and:

```
<div class="popupContent" id="productTip348_27598"> ... </div>
```

The idea is that, I, by hovering over the link, will have the div.popupContent with the same ID shown by magic. There will be multiple elements with the same classes, just the ID's are varying.

I'm unfortunately not a jQuery wizard, so I'm looking for a bit of help with this.

Comment: You said "ID's are varying" yet you are showing two different elements with the same id, which is illegal and might/will lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

As has been stated in the comments, your example here has duplicate `id` attributes being used, which is invalid.

Instead, try putting the `id` of the div to show in the `href` atrtribute of the `a` element:

```
<a class="popup" href="#productTip348_27598">Link text</a>
```

Then in jQuery, use the `href` to show the related div on hover:

```
$(".popup").hover(
    function() {
        $($(this).attr("href")).show();
    },
    function() {
        $($(this).attr("href")).hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: You're right - I've had to revise the code a bit and switch some values around to make it work properly (and valid). Instead, I've come to a much better result, commented in below.
Thanks though, for lending a hand. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is `.popupContent` placed within `.popup` element? If so;

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.popup').hover(
    function() { // Triggered on both mouseenter and mouseleave events
      $(this).find('.popupContent').toggle();
    }
  );

});
```

"div.popupContent with the same ID".

IDs are unique and can not be shared with other elements.

Comment: You're right, I've had to change the code a bit to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result I came up with, with the help of a friend.

Changed the name of the class assigned to the hover element.
Changed the ID of the popup to that of data-id, so it was a bit more unique and valid at the same time.

```
$(".popupLink").hover(function(){
    var selectedId = $(this).attr("id");
    $('[data-id='+selectedId +']').toggle()
});
```

With this I was able to achieve my goal.

Thanks, however, to those giving their input to this topic. Much appreciated. :)